# Importing GLTF file into Blender creates a strange mask / backdrop over the scene

Tags: gltf

I don’t know how to describe this. I imported this model from Sketchup. There’s a gray backdrop over the scene. It’s not an object. It can not be selected. It doesn’t have a layer. It looks like a volumetric object but its not. Mostly likely a bug or some settings in my blender is off.

[image: gray thing]

Comment: It looks rather like a clipping problem.  Haven't got vers 2.8 but in earlier versions you press N in the 3D window then open the "View" tab.  Set the max clipping value to a much higher number.  I usually work on 1500 for larger projects.

Comment: This is it. Thanks!